# WSO2 contentType text/html overlap with application/xml in axis2.xml

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have two APIs. Someone returning to contentType text/html. Other one returning contentType application/xml.

I added this parameter in WSO2/ axis2.xml file for wso2 should read to text/html

And i got succes from API but now other API ( i mean return to application/xml) , thats not working correct.

Can someone help me please? How should i do?

Thanks

Comment: i added this parameter in axis2.xml file                                                                                
<messageFormatter class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter" contentType="text/html"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enable message relay, so that messages of a specific content type are not built or formatted but simply pass through the ESB, you can specify the message relay builder (org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder) for that content type. Make sure that you specify message builder and formatter for both the content types (application/xml , text/html). Refer to the following sample configuration. You need to add these in the axis2.xml file under messageFormatters and messageBuilders.

Message formatters

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/xml"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter"/>
<messageFormatter contentType="text/html"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

Message builders

```
<messageBuilder contentType="text/xml"
                       class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
<messageBuilder contentType="application/xml"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"/>
```

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Configuring+Message+Relay

Comment: I added these parameters and API started to return binary. And i did transform base64 to   text. That's working. Thanks!